# Convert const char* to wstring

Tags: c++

I'm working on a native extension for a zinc based flash application and I need to convert a `const char*` to a `wstring`.

This is my code:

```
mdmVariant_t* appendHexDataToFile(const zinc4CallInfo_t *pCallInfo, int paramCount, mdmVariant_t **params) {

    if(paramCount >= 2) {
        const char *file    = mdmVariantGetString(params[0]);
        const char *data    = mdmVariantGetString(params[1]);

        return mdmVariantNewInt(native.AppendHexDataToFile(file, data));
    }
    else {
        return mdmVariantNewBoolean(FALSE);
    }
}
```

But `native.AppendHexDataToFile()` needs two `wstring`.
I'm not very good with C++ and I think all those different string types are totally confusing and I didn't find something useful in the net. So I'm asking you guys how to do it.

**Edit**: The Strings are UTF-8 and I'm using OSX and Windows XP/Vista/7

Comment: Before you try to deal with chars and wide chars, you should be able to answer the following question: **How are you strings encoded** and what conversion do you intend to do ?

Comment: In addition to @ereOn which plattform are you using?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I recommend you using `std::string` instead of C-style strings (`char*`) wherever possible. You can create `std::string` object from `const char*` by simple passing it to its constructor.

Once you have `std::string`, you can create simple function that will convert `std::string` containing multi-byte UTF-8 characters to `std::wstring` containing UTF-16 encoded points (16bit representation of special characters from `std::string`).

There are more ways how to do that, here's the way by using [MultiByteToWideChar function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& str)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo( size_needed, 0 );
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}
```

Check these questions too:
[Mapping multibyte characters to their unicode point representation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6107776/1168156)
[Why use MultiByteToWideCharArray to convert std::string to std::wstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4582951/1168156)

Comment: **Disclaimer:** `MultiByteToWideChar` is a Windows-only function. (OP is using Windows but question is tagged just `c++`)

Comment: It would be best if your solution is cross platform.

Comment: @huahsin68 This is still the best conversion on Windows. As MS says [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752(v=vs.85).aspx), _"Your application can convert between Windows code pages and OEM code pages using the standard C runtime library functions. However, use of these functions presents a risk of data loss because the characters that can be represented by each code page do not match exactly"_
However, I wonder if one should use the CP_ACP codepage when converting strings obtained through WINAPI ...A() functions (for example, from GetWindowTextA)

Answer (score 23):

You can convert `char` string to `wstring` directly as following code:

```
char buf1[] = "12345678901234567890";
wstring ws(&buf1[0], &buf1[20]);
```

Comment: Or more generic: `wstring ws(buf1, buf1 + strlen(buf1));` if you don't know buf1's length at design time.

Comment: Note that it doesn't solve the UTF-8 problematic mentioned in the question. But for a known ascii <128 string (if it's your prerequisite), it works just fine.

Answer (score 16):

AFAIK this works only from C++11 and above:

```
#include <codecvt>

// ...

std::wstring stringToWstring(const std::string& t_str)
{
    //setup converter
    typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_type;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;

    //use converter (.to_bytes: wstr->str, .from_bytes: str->wstr)
    return converter.from_bytes(t_str);
}
```

[Reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374698/1178267)

**Update**

As indicated in the comments, <codecvt> seems to be deprecated in C++17. See here: [Deprecated header <codecvt> replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946335/deprecated-header-codecvt-replacement)

Comment: Deprecated in C++17

Comment: @EnricoDetoma what exactly is deprecated?

Comment: std::wstring_convert is not available without including #include <locale> at least in my Ubuntu box

Answer (score 2):

You need a library that can encode/decode UTF8.  Unfortunately, this functionality isn't included with the std c++ library.  Here's one library you might use: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Here's an example use of it:

```
utf8::utf8to32(bytes.begin(), bytes.end(), std::back_inserter(wstr));
```

Answer (score 0):

On OS X wstring uses UTF-32 rather than UTF-16. You can do the conversion like this:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

// make facets usable by giving them a public destructor
template <class Facet>
class usable_facet
    : public Facet
{
public:
    template <class ...Args>
        usable_facet(Args&& ...args)
            : Facet(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    ~usable_facet() {}
};

std::wstring s2ws(std::string const &s) {
    std::wstring_convert<
        usable_facet<std::codecvt<char32_t,char,std::mbstate_t>>
        ,char32_t> convert;
    std::u32string utf32 = convert.from_bytes(s);
    static_assert(sizeof(wchar_t)==sizeof(char32_t),"char32_t and wchar_t must have same size");
    return {begin(utf32),end(utf32)};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32697209/634821) from @anhoppe. Here's how to convert `char*`:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale> 

// ...

std::wstring stringToWstring(const char* utf8Bytes)
{
    //setup converter
    using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8<typename std::wstring::value_type>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, typename std::wstring::value_type> converter;

    //use converter (.to_bytes: wstr->str, .from_bytes: str->wstr)
    return converter.from_bytes(utf8Bytes);
}
```

And here's how to convert `char*` if you also already know the length of the buffer:

```
#include <codecvt>

// ...

std::wstring stringToWstring(const char* utf8Bytes, const size_t numBytes)
{
    //setup converter
    using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8<typename std::wstring::value_type>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, typename std::wstring::value_type> converter;

    //use converter (.to_bytes: wstr->str, .from_bytes: str->wstr)
    return converter.from_bytes(utf8Bytes, utf8Bytes + numBytes);
}
```

Comment: std::wstring_convert is not available without including #include <locale> at least in my Ubuntu box

Answer (score -2):

Here's a code I found;

```
std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string& s)
 {
 std::wstring temp(s.length(),L' ');
 std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
 return temp; 
 }
```

And here's the original forum post with a possible second solution using the windows API function MultiByteToWideChar:

http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-193852.html

Comment: What if std::string passed to this function contains multi-byte characters that need to be converted to UTF-16 encoded wide chars equivalents?

Comment: Why not ' '? it will be erased anyway by the copy function. It's just an arbitrary char to make room for the string.

Comment: Then why would you initialize these characters to `' '` when you know that they are going to be rewritten?

Comment: because the copy function does not create a buffer. The buffer needs to be created first, which is done by the constructor.

Comment: Ah, sorry I see now. I thought that [basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has also constructor that takes only `size_type count`, just like `std::vector` has.

Comment: This will not convert UTF-8 encoded characters outside the ASCII range to whatever encoding `std::wstring` uses. It simply copies, truncates, and destroys data. This is not a solution.