# How to use FindResourceW() Properly?

Tags: c++, winapi

A simple example here I want to load some embedded text file to my application but when I use `FindResourceW` I get compile-time error:

```
HGLOBAL     res_handle = NULL;
HRSRC       res;
wchar_t*    res_data;
DWORD       res_size;

// NOTE: providing g_hInstance is important, NULL might not work
res = FindResourceW(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(MY_RESOURCE), RT_RCDATA);
if (!res)
    return 1;
```

In my `.rc` file I defined the resource like this:

```
MY_RESOURCE RCDATA    L"Help topics.txt"
```

The error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  C2664   'HRSRC
>   FindResourceW(HMODULE,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 3
>   from 'LPSTR' to
>   'LPCWSTR' FindFilesProj   C:\Users\WongFei\Desktop\FindFilesProj
>   UNICODE\WinMain.cpp   674

Comment: you need define `UNICODE`

Comment: But I think it is defined by default in `msvc++ 14.0` isn't it?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: Yes thanks. Now it compiles correctly but nothing loaded.

Comment: defined `RT_RCDATA` as `MAKEINTRESOURCE(10)` . `MAKEINTRESOURCE` defined as `MAKEINTRESOURCEW` if defined `UNICODE` otherwise as `MAKEINTRESOURCEA` - from your error visible that `RT_RCDATA` expanded to `MAKEINTRESOURCEA` - so you need define `UNICODE` in project settings

Comment: are `MY_RESOURCE` defined equal in .rc and cpp file ?

Comment: @RbMm: `MY_RESURCE` is defined in the header file and in `rc` file.

Comment: if *but nothing loaded* faster of all resource not found in exe. usual due different resource name. look in pe viewer how actual your resource named

Comment: Now the return value is null `if(!res)` succeeds! What is the problem now?

Comment: are `#define MY_RESOURCE 1000` visible in rc file ? you include `myres.h` to it ?

Comment: @RbMm: Ah! yes I'll try it thanx

Comment: of course in this case `.rc` can not know that `MY_RESOURCE` is 1000 (from where ? why not 453 ?) and treat it as string `"MY_RESOURCE"`

Comment: @RbMm: Thank you very much it solves the problem.

Comment: @RbMm: If you posted it as an answer it'll be an accepted good answer.

Comment: You text file must be unicode too!

Comment: @xMRi: I saved it with `notepad++` as `UTF-8 BOM` but it doesn't help?

Comment: Windows uses UTF-16. In you case you have to convert it after loading using MultiByteToWideChar.

Comment: @xMRi: I don't know how. Please add answer.

Comment: REad the MSDN Doku. There are thousand samples in the net. Just Google: This was the first link I found in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766838/converting-file-in-utf-8-to-utf-16)

Comment: Please stop changing the question. Your next problems are not part of this question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ok.

Comment: But there's also no point asking a new question  about that because it has been asked hundreds of times already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `RT_RCDATA`, which is defined as:

```
#define RT_RCDATA           MAKEINTRESOURCE(10)
```

And `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` is defined as:

```
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEA(i) ((LPSTR)((ULONG_PTR)((WORD)(i))))
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEW(i) ((LPWSTR)((ULONG_PTR)((WORD)(i))))
#ifdef UNICODE
#define MAKEINTRESOURCE  MAKEINTRESOURCEW
#else
#define MAKEINTRESOURCE  MAKEINTRESOURCEA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

You have a project were `UNICODE` isn't defined. So `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` returns a `char*` but `FindeResourceW()` wants a `wchar_t*` instead.  Thus the compiler error.  You can't use `RT_RCDATA` as-is in combination with `FindResourceW()` when `UNICODE` isn't defined.

Use `FindResource()` instead of `FindResourceW()`. This makes sure that `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` returns a pointer of the same type (UNICODE or non-UNICODE) that `FindResource()` expects:

```
res = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_RESOURCE), RT_RCDATA);
```

Otherwise, you have to type-cast `RT_RCDATA` to `wchar_t*` to match what `FindResourceW()` expects:

```
 res = FindResourceW(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(MY_RESOURCE), (LPWSTR)RT_RCDATA);
```

The type-cast is safe.

Remember that your resource is stored in the way you created it. There may be need to convert it into the proper character mode you need.

Comment: The problem is with `RT_RCDATA` because `UNICODE` is not defined.

Comment: Jupp RT_RCDATA sis defined as MAKEINTRESOURCE(10). So the conflict is there. And there is no RT_RCDATAA and RT_RCDATAW

Comment: Changed my answer.

Comment: No need for the resource itself to be Unicode encoded

Comment: Yes. I Just read his changed question again... and answered accordingly. You are right.... I change the text again.

Comment: @xMRi: I am so sorry for changing the topic.