# C++. Convert char* with unicode (UTF-8) symbols to std::wstring

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, tinyxml2

I faced with pretty common problem, but I can't find solution for this. tinyxml2 library returning `const char*` with `Attribute(const char*)` method. In xml file, opened with that library, I have attributes with unicode and without. File converted to UTF-8. Using Linux, but it would be nice to see solution for windows too. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking...are you asking how to convert the `const char *` the library is returning to a `std::wstring`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737644/convert-const-char-to-wstring

Comment: Have you used swprintf() function? Take a look here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx)

Comment: @BrianGradin Ye I asked exactly what you wrote. But your link will work just for windows and I already find it. (But anyway thanks for it, because it's kinda windows solution). But now I need linux solution.

Comment: @QuestionAndAnswer Ye, I saw that link, but it's windows solution. I saw another solution lower with utf8 library, but i would solve this without libraries. (If it's impossible I will use lib)

Answer (score -2):

Like this:

```
std::wstring utf8_decode(const std::string &str) 
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo( size_needed, 0 );
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}
```

Comment: What, is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but is that really [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10738141/2302862)?

Comment: @Siguza pretty much yeah, I put it together from google searches (as normal.) I created it when messing with GDI+ because it requires unicode.

Comment: The code is **identical**, down to formatting, variable naming, and choice of casts as that of the [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10738141/1889329).

Comment: @IInspectable you're right, I guess I just didn't remember. I just remembered looking at the `MultiByteToWideChar` function in a book googling and MSDN.